# Modify and access value outside a thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, arraylist

I am new to OOP, especially in Java. So, i have a difficulty to access and delete values in ArrayList from two classes.

I have a **Counter** class in which i have only an ArrayList that i have to call it from two different classes.

```
public class Counter12 {
   public static ArrayList<String> clientsStorage = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Class **Server12**

```
public class Server12 {
//public static int counter = 0;
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    //Create a server socket, bounds to a specified port
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5016);
    System.out.println("Server started");
    //int counter = 0;
    //ArrayList<String> clientsStorage = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (true) {
        //counter++;
        Socket serverClient = serverSocket.accept();    //Wait for client to connect      
        ServerClientThread sct = new ServerClientThread(serverClient);
        sct.start();          
    }
}
```

Class **ServerClientThread** is a Thread class where i am adding some values in the ArrayList

```
public class ServerClientThread extends Thread{

Socket serverClient;
//int counter;

//int counter = 0;
   ServerClientThread(Socket inSocket) {
       serverClient = inSocket;
       //clientNo = counter;

}

   private volatile ArrayBlockingQueue<String> clientsStorage = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
   //ArrayList<String> clientsStorage = new ArrayList<String>();
public void run(){  
      //counter++;
      try {
          ObjectInputStream inputValues = new ObjectInputStream(serverClient.getInputStream());
          Student12 received = (Student12) inputValues.readObject();

          if (received.getName().equals("Wrong!")) {

                //represent object to a text-output stream
                //System.out.println("Clients connected: " + clientNo);
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(serverClient.getOutputStream(), true);
                output.println("Wrong typed value.Try again!");
                output.println("Name: Johny Domino Domino");
                output.println("Age: 27");
                output.println("Mark: 2");
                output.println("Email: johny_domino@gmx.com");
               // output.println("Clients connected: " + clientNo);
               inputValues.close();
                output.close();
                //serverClient.close();


            } 
            else {
                Counter12.clientsStorage.add(received.getName());
                int clientsNumber = Counter12.clientsStorage.size();

                System.out.println("Clients: " + clientsNumber);
                System.out.println("Client accepted: " + received.getName());
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(serverClient.getOutputStream(), true);
                output.println("Student " + received.getName() + received.getEmail() + " has been received");
               output.println("Clients: " + clientsNumber);
                inputValues.close();
                output.close();
                //serverClient.close();

            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }
```

}

In **Client** class i should remove some values from the ArrayList but i can't because the program showed me that the ArrayList is empty

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;
//Creating fields, labels and area using JFrame class
JLabel labelName;
JLabel labelAge;
JLabel labelMark;
JLabel labelEmail;

JTextField txtFieldName;
JTextField txtFieldAge;
JTextField txtFieldMark;
JTextField txtFieldEmail;

JButton btnProcess;
JButton btnAddClient;
JButton btnLeave;
JButton btnExit;


JTextArea txtArea;



public Client12() {

     //Set parameters   
    this.setTitle("Simple Sample");
    this.setSize(420, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    labelName = new JLabel("Full Name: ");
    labelName.setBounds(10, 10, 120, 21);
    add(labelName);


    txtFieldName = new JTextField(); 
    txtFieldName.setBounds(105, 10, 120, 21);
    add(txtFieldName);

    labelAge = new JLabel("Age: ");
    labelAge.setBounds(10, 35, 120, 21);
    add(labelAge);

    txtFieldAge = new JTextField();
    txtFieldAge.setBounds(105, 35, 120, 21);
    add(txtFieldAge);

    labelMark = new JLabel("Mark: ");
    labelMark.setBounds(10, 60, 120, 21);
    add(labelMark);

    txtFieldMark = new JTextField();
    txtFieldMark.setBounds(105, 60, 120, 21);
    add(txtFieldMark);

    labelEmail = new JLabel("Email: ");
    labelEmail.setBounds(10, 85, 120, 21);
    add(labelEmail);

    txtFieldEmail = new JTextField();
    txtFieldEmail.setBounds(105, 85, 120, 21);
    add(txtFieldEmail);

    btnProcess = new JButton("Process");
    btnProcess.setBounds(250, 40, 120, 21);
    btnProcess.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnProcess);

    btnAddClient = new JButton("Add Client");
    btnAddClient.setBounds(250, 70, 120, 21);
    btnAddClient.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnAddClient);

    btnLeave = new JButton("Client Leave");
    btnLeave.setBounds(250, 100, 120, 21);
    btnLeave.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnLeave);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(250, 130, 120, 21);
    btnExit.addActionListener(this);
    add(btnExit);

    txtArea = new JTextArea();
    txtArea.setBounds(10, 120, 385, 150);
    txtArea.setLineWrap(true);
    txtArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    add(txtArea);


    this.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Client12(); 
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(btnProcess)) {
        try {
            processInformation();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (event.getSource().equals(btnAddClient)){
        new Client12();
    }

    else if (event.getSource().equals(btnLeave)){

        Counter12.clientsStorage.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Clients: " + Counter12.clientsStorage.size());
        setVisible(false);
        dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object.
    }

    else if (event.getSource().equals(btnExit)){
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


//Method that process input information
public void processInformation() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5016);
    ObjectOutputStream p = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    String name = txtFieldName.getText();
    String markStr = txtFieldMark.getText();
    String ageStr = txtFieldAge.getText();   
    String email = txtFieldEmail.getText();

    //Checks if the user entered a properly formatted name, mark, age and email
    //RegEx name
    String patternName = ("^[A-Z]+[a-z]+\\s[A-Z]+[a-z]+\\s[A-Z]+[a-z]+$");
    Pattern patternCompileName = Pattern.compile(patternName);
    Matcher matcherName = patternCompileName.matcher(name);

    //RegEx mark
    String patternMark = ("^[0-6]$");
    Pattern patternCompileMark = Pattern.compile(patternMark);
    Matcher matcherMark = patternCompileMark.matcher(String.valueOf(markStr));

    //RegEx age
    String patternAge = ("\\d");
    Pattern patternCompileAge = Pattern.compile(patternAge);
    Matcher matcherAge = patternCompileAge.matcher(String.valueOf(ageStr));

    //RegEx email
    String patternEmail = ("[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-z]{2,5}");
    Pattern patternCompileEmail = Pattern.compile(patternEmail);
    Matcher matcherEmail = patternCompileEmail.matcher(email);

    int mark = 0;
    int age = 0;

    //Match the regular expressions
    if (matcherName.find() && matcherMark.find() && matcherAge.find() && matcherEmail.find()) {

         //counter++;
         mark = Integer.parseInt(markStr);
         age = Integer.parseInt(ageStr);
         //writes primitive data of the object to an OutputStream
         p.writeObject(new Student12(name, age, mark, email));
         p.flush();

        //Read the details from server
         BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 s.getInputStream()));

         txtArea.setText("The server respond: " + response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append(response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         btnProcess.setEnabled(false);
         p.close();   
         response.close();
         s.close();
        // txtFieldName.setText("");
         //txtFieldAge.setText("");
        // txtFieldMark.setText("");
        // txtFieldEmail.setText("");
    }
    else {
        //If RegEx is false, we will set name = "Wrong!"
        p.writeObject(new Student12("Wrong!", age, mark, email));
        p.flush();

     BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream()));

         txtArea.setText("The server respond: " + response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append("Example: " + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append(response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append(response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append(response.readLine() + "\r\n");
         txtArea.append(response.readLine());
         p.close();
         response.close();
         s.close();

        // txtFieldName.setText("");
         //txtFieldAge.setText("");
        // txtFieldMark.setText("");
         //txtFieldEmail.setText("");
    }  
}
```

What should i do to add values from ServerClientThread class and to remove them from Client class?

Comment: Doing multithreading while being new in the language is like navigating the ocean while learning to sail.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it's an university assignment. I have to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision is that i had to create a new method in "Client" class after "Leave Client" button is pressed. In this method i created a new socket, outputstream and just create new student with some unique name to go into the run() method(via "BufferedReader") in the Thread class. After that in the Thread i am using take() method do remove the queue from the ArrayBlockingQueue.

**Client** class

```
 else if (event.getSource().equals(btnLeave)){
        if (!btnProcess.getModel().isEnabled()) {
            try {
                removeClient();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            setVisible(false);
            dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object.
        }
    }

public void removeClient()throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5016);
    ObjectOutputStream p = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    p.writeObject(new Student("Remove Client!", 27, 2, "remove_client@gmx.com"));
    p.flush();

    BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    txtArea.setText("The server respond: " + response.readLine() + "\r\n");
}
```

**ServerClientThread** class

```
else if (received.getName().equals("Remove Client!")) {

              Counter.clientsStorage.take();
              System.out.println("Client removed");
              System.out.println("Clients: " + Counter.clientsStorage.size());
              PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(serverClient.getOutputStream(), true);
              output.println("Student removed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an ArrayList as a queue: you are adding at the end, and removing from the beginning. So it's better to use the `Queue` interface. A typical queue implementation for multithreaded applications is [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html). Use that instead of `ArrayList`.

It seems that one of your threads is trying to read a value from your arraylist before the other thread has written it. With ArrayBlockingQueue, the reading thread will wait for the other thread to write the value.

Comment: The problem is that i am trying to remove the thread via Client class. I have some JFrame textbox and when i click add client it add it in the Counter class. When i try to remove it the List is empty. There is no added values...

Comment: Are you definitely trying to remove from the arraylist AFTER the value is added? It seems to me that you are running two threads in parallel and the thread that removes the value is try to do so before the value is added.

Comment: Yes i think the same way. I am going to edit the code to be more clear.

Comment: In your updated code, the shared "queue" `Counter12.clientsStorage` is still just an ArrayList. You seem to have created a private ArrayBlockingQueue variable with the same name in class ServerClientThread which you don't use at all. Have you tried changing `Counter12.clientsStorage` to ArrayBlockingQueue?

Comment: Yes, i tried. I just paste the old code and did not delete some modifications which i tried. I tried with everything you told me. The problem is that i am trying to remove the value but obviously it is not added. But i can't understand why. When i check in the thread class it is added, but when i try to remove it from the client class it is not there. May be i should try to remove it in different way but do not know how. This is the last thing i have to do in this project. Just to make counter, when i close one of the threads the the counter to decrease.

Comment: Hold on, in Client.actionPerformed() you're calling remove() first and checking size() after. Are you sure it's not actually succeeding? How do you tell that the list was empty before removal?

Comment: If i remove the line "Counter12.clientsStorage.remove(0);" and only print the size i see that is emtpy. If i try to remove it it shows me an exception...

Comment: If you are using an ArrayBlockingQueue, make sure you remove an element using `take()` and not `remove()`. If the queue is currently empty, your client thread will wait until a server adds something to the queue. If you are getting an exception, it means you are not removing correctly (using `take()`). The `remove(0)` call on a Queue will attempt to remove the object `Integer.valueOf(0)` which of course doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `ArrayList` to `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. It's Thread-safe. If you're using Threads consider using `synchronize` blocks, thread-safe classes from `java.util.concurrent` or thread-safe collections from Guava library.
2. Also, if you're using Threads consider **not using** static fields.
3. If you want one thread to supply some values, and other to retrieve them, consider changing `List<>` to other collections like `Stack` or `Queue`.
4. For cleaner code, try to utilize java polymorphism mechanisms:

   `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I tried with List<String> list = new ArrayList<>() and i remove "static" but it is the same. I think the problem is in my Counter12 class. May be i should use some getters and setters...

Comment: `List<String>` is only for clean code :) Try using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.